# Network LAN manual

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I have a few problems with LAN Ethernet.

Laptop shall be NFS server for a small board, like Pi. Right now I am operating with GUI Network manager and set a fix IP to my `enp3s0` (why not `eth0` ???).

As metric seems to be higher than WLAN, from that moment I don't have connection to internet. I am not a network guru, but what I found after several hours - it helps to change routing that way:

```
sudo route add -host <IP BOARD> (192.168.3.102) dev enp3s0
sudo route del -net 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev enp3s0
```

That has a few drawbacks. As ethernet setting disappears as soon as LAN connection is off, it takes a while until connection is re-established. You know, a testboard will often be repowered ;)

Even worse is, that I have to type routing commands again and again.
So two questions:

- How can I setup Ubuntu 16.04 such that the LAN keeps its setting even if not
  wired? (Read about NetworkManager.conf, but ignore-carrier seems not
  to be a valid setting).
- Where and how can I make this routing information static, so that I
  don't have to type it in again and again?

Routing table after connection LAN of Laptop with board is:

default         192.168.3.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp3s0
default         192.168.3.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.3.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp3s0
192.168.3.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0

Comment: Have you tried using the IPv6 link-local address of the device? Since IPv6 link-local addresses don't require any configuration at all, they should work better for what you are doing than IPv4.

Comment: No, sorry, I have no experience at all with IPv6. Won't make the problem growing, as all other devices in my network (embedded too) have just ipv4.

Comment: That attitude is the reason networking is so complicated these days. IPv6 is simpler to work with than IPv4. But supporting systems that still only supports IPv4 (which was obsolete a decade ago) can be a nightmare. If you insist on only using an obsolete and complicated protocol, then I don't think I can help you.

Comment: Can you describe your router/gateway? It should be providing this routing information to your laptop.   Also, what are your routes ( `route` ) before making your modification?

Comment: As "new lines" seems not to work in comment, I updated router table above.       Hope that makes it a bit clearer